# Quarks, and their effects

Tags: quarks

Can someone explain to me the physical effect of quarks on matter, and what each different quark does compared to the other?

Comment: I've seen descriptions of up, down, and even strange quarks, but have yet to understand what they actually do, also, I've heard of the existence of the charm quark and have yet to see and specific details about it, other than unreliable sources.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

1. quarks are elementary pointlike particles, with rest mass, together with electrons, which have rest mass too they build up everything you know as matter
2. they build up the nuclei
3. the nuclei and electrons EM repulsion gives atoms and matter stiffness and spatial volume, that is why matter is not crushed into a single point by gravity, because on the micro level the EM force and strong force is much stronger then gravity
4. the strong force (and residual strong force) is what keeps nuclei together

quarks have different types, but their differences are more on the energy level and mass, EM charge, isospin.

Comment: So, the strong force provides practically a binding agent for the quarks, which make up protons and neutrons, forming the nucleus, and the electrons are themselves elementary particles that work together with the quarks to create an atom essentially the building blocks of all matter. Thank you